# MUI toggle button selected input not being highlighted despite setting value

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

The MUI toggle is able to register the user input but the selected input does not get highlighted when clicked. I have added value parameter and did an onChange function to change the param on value change. It does get highlighted at "Not Final" initially, but once I toggle it, the highlight disappears and neither options are highlighted. What am I doing wrong?

```
 <ToggleButtonGroup
  color="primary"
  exclusive
  value={formData.isFinal}
  onChange={(e) => changeData(e.target.value,'isFinal')}
  aria-label="Platform"
            >
    <ToggleButton value={true} >Final</ToggleButton>
    <ToggleButton value={false}>Not Final</ToggleButton>
</ToggleButtonGroup>
```

```
 const changeData = (data, type) => {
      setFormData((prevData) => ({
        ...prevData,
        [type]: data,
      }));
  };
```

```
 const [formData, setFormData] = useState({
   name: '',
   description: null,
   isFinal: false,
 });
```

Comment: The group should use strings as values, not true/false.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The type of data parameter of the `changeData` handler is string.
In a word, if you toggle it, the data is either "true" or "false".
I recommend you to not use `boolean` value as a value prop of `ToggleButton`.

Comment: oh yes you're right. may I know why it  converts from boolean to string?

Comment: The boolean value as a prop in JSX has special meaning. That's why. if you pass a props without value, the props is referenced to true.